# Why does the unilateral 6-OHDA lesion Parkinson's model cause ipsilateral rotations?

Tags: neuroscience

As far as I understand, the loss of dopaminergic neurons should hinder movement in the contralateral side of the body, resulting in contralateral rotations when the animal tries to move forward.

Comment: Welcome to cogsci.SE!  You might have more luck with answers if you could cite or link to more information.

Comment: Depends on what drug you give them: http://www.lifetechnologies.com/us/en/home/references/protocols/neurobiology/neurobiology-protocols/using-neural-cells-for-cell-therapy.html

Comment: @Penguiness If you extend on the link and quote the relevant sections this could be an answer. As you posted it before, it was not, hence I turned it into a comment.